# How to use a previously initialised object in a different class?

Tags: java

I have a class (CheckHotel) holding an object (Hotel) which contains a set of objects nested within (Room within Hotel, Bed within Room). They all already have values set and I'd like to use these objects with these values in a different class, but I've been unable to find a way to do it.

My object:

```
static class Hotel {
    [...]
    Class Room {
        [...]
        Class Bed {
            [...]
        }
    }
}
```

The method of the other class (BuildReport) that I'm trying to pass it to:

```
public static void createReport(Hotel Hotel) {
    [...]
}
```

and the line I'm trying to use to call that method (in CheckHotel):

```
BuildReport.createReport(HotelN);
```

HotelN being the name of the object of Hotel that I want to move across. Doing that pulled up the error:

```
'The method createReport(Hotel) from the type BuildReport refers to the missing type Hotel'
```

in the main class, and

```
'Hotel cannot be resolved as a type'
```

in the parameters of the method I'm trying to call.

I'm using Eclipse, which recommended adding:

```
import CheckHotel.Hotel;
```

to BuildReport, but that just created the following error:

```
'The import CheckHotel cannot be resolved'
```

Does anybody have any idea how to fix this? The only solutions online that I've been able to find were for just creating a brand new instance of the object in the new class, but I need to use the object with the same values that I already have.

Comment: You're using Eclipse, so use Ctrl+Shift+O to organise imports automatically. Imports must contain the full path to a class.

Comment: I've tried Ctrl+Shift+O but it hasn't helped; it just removes 'import CheckHotel.Hotel' then recommends that I add it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cIt may not be directly linked to the answer but your class name is CheckHotel and package name too is CheckHotel. That is not advisable. Try giving package name to be differen say "hotelmanagement" , keep CheckHotel class inside that so your import statement will change to import hotelmanagement.CheckHotel;